# Deploying FastAPI app that uses stable-baselines3 using Deta

Tags: python, fastapi, stable-baselines

I developed a machine learning-based App that uses the [stable-baselines3](https://pypi.org/project/stable-baselines3/) library (a Reinforcement learning library). The app is working fine when tested locally using uvicorn. However, when I deploy the app to Deta, it throws the following error:

```
Adding dependencies...
Error: failed to update dependencies: Internal server error
```

I removed all dependencies one by one and I am now sure that the problem is in stable-baselines3, I have no idea why? please any explanation/solution for this?